# Where to download the previous SDK for CRM 2011 v 5.0.12?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

Currently searching for CRM 2011 SDK always seems to yield [this](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24004) download page, which is the most current version of the SDK (As of this post, its version 5.0.13 for rollup 12).  We are going to be installing rollup 11, on our prod boxes this month.  I'd like to get the previous version of the SDK, but have been unable to find it.  Does anyone happen to have a link to the 5.0.12 version of the SDK?

Answer (score 0):

I had to downgrade recently and used [this link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29692). And I'm not sure if a newer version is recommended. Definitely not UR12.

And for UR11, it's probably [this link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34969).

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: That's the download for rollup 8.  It also doesn't have the SDK on it.  I'm looking for the SDK download for rollup 11.

Comment: @Daryl The other link is for 11, isn't it? But I didn't check if it's got SDK. I just assumed it. Feel free to -1 me for not being thorough. I just did a new search and realized that I underestimated your issue. Sorry. I wonder if there are any (significant) differences between SDKs. I can ask a MVP at work, if you want me to.

Comment: I'm not sure there is any difference as well... We reference the dlls from the rollup any way... but I guess I woudl be concerned about the late bound entity creation with the CrmSrvcUtil and the plugin registration possibly changing...

Comment: @Daryl As for plugin registration, I think that you need not to worry. I recall that I at a point by mistake and unknowingly used different roll-up versions on the development and production servers and noticed no issues. Of course, Murphy tells us that stuff **you** will do are going to give you a huge boom on the server at the most convenient occasion. :)