# Plugin Registration Tool source code

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

From version 5.0.13 the source code of Plugin Registration Tool is not available inside the CRM 2011 SDK (the executable is inside bin folder)

Because Microsoft only hosts the latest version, the source code isn't available anymore.

Someone has a link to download the SDK 5.0.12?

I asked this question on StackOverflow because that source code is a good example for some messages available for the CRM 2011 platform.

Comment: Do you happen to have these files Guido?  The links in the answer are gone, and my zip is missing some references apparently...

Comment: yes I have the source on my onedrive, give me a sec

Comment: here you go http://1drv.ms/1p7ZjNK you still need the CRM 2011 SDK for some .cs references (like deviceregistration.cs if I remember right)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Microsoft SDK link is only the [latest and greatest version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14569987/where-to-download-the-previous-sdk-for-crm-2011-v-5-0-12)...  I have the 5.0.6 SDK  version of the tool that I'm happy to share [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0By9PBv_3cDOXdzc19xeThRaWs/edit?usp=sharing)

The tool in the XrmToolBox might also be a good place to look.

Comment: Thansk Daryl, for now I will keep open the question, maybe someone else has other versions too.